# Angular 10+ building to absolute path is missing de index.html file

Tags: angular, build, path, absolute

When I try to build my app using an absolute outputPath everything compiles correctly and copy all the files but the index.html file is missing.

`ng build -c homo`

if I change the outputDir property to an relative path like "dist/homo" the index.html file is included and everything works fine.

Am I doing something wrong?

My angular.json:

```
"projects": {
        "my-project": {
            "root": "",
            "sourceRoot": "src",
            "projectType": "application",
            "architect": {
                "build": {
                    "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
                    "options": {
                        "outputPath": "dist",
                        "index": "src/index.html",
                        "main": "src/main.ts",
                        "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
                        "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
                        "assets": [ ... ],
                        "styles": [ ... ],
                        "scripts": [ ... ]
                    },
                    "configurations": {
                        "homo": {
                            "assets": [ ... ],
                            "outputPath": "\\\\10.10.10.135\\custfolder\\myProyect",
                            "optimization": false,
                            "outputHashing": "all",
                            "sourceMap": false,
                            "extractCss": true,
                            "namedChunks": false,
                            "aot": true,
                            "extractLicenses": true,
                            "vendorChunk": false,
                            "buildOptimizer": true,
                            "fileReplacements": [{
                                "replace": "src/config/config.ts",
                                "with": "src/config/config.homo.ts"
                            }],
                            "serviceWorker": true,
                            "ngswConfigPath": "ngsw-config.json"
                        },

...
```

My Angular CLI version

```
     _                      _                 ____ _     ___
    / \   _ __   __ _ _   _| | __ _ _ __     / ___| |   |_ _|
   / △ \ | '_ \ / _` | | | | |/ _` | '__|   | |   | |    | |
  / ___ \| | | | (_| | |_| | | (_| | |      | |___| |___ | |
 /_/   \_\_| |_|\__, |\__,_|_|\__,_|_|       \____|_____|___|
                |___/
    

Angular CLI: 10.1.2
Node: 14.13.1
OS: win32 x64

Angular: 10.1.2
... animations, cli, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic, platform-server
... router, service-worker, upgrade
Ivy Workspace: Yes

Package                         Version
---------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect       0.900.7
@angular-devkit/build-angular   0.1001.2
@angular-devkit/core            10.1.2
@angular-devkit/schematics      10.1.2
@angular/cdk                    10.2.2
@angular/fire                   5.4.2
@angular/pwa                    0.900.7
@schematics/angular             9.0.7
@schematics/update              0.1001.2
rxjs                            6.6.3
typescript                      4.0.3
```